# Change content color depending on background color on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, overlay, background-color

I am looking to find a method of changing content color (overlaying content) dynamically as a user scrolls a page, depending on what the background color is. Mainly I just want to give the content a light color if against a dark bakground, and vice versa - it just needs to be either black or white. How would one approach this using JavaScript? Any ideas?

Comment: post a fiddle for something that you have tried

Comment: Uhm, not much - http://jsfiddle.net/pcY2Q/

Answer (score 0):

You can use function document.elementFromPoint( *x, y* ) that returns the most deeply nested child of the document at point ( x, y ).

You can check the background color of the element at point somewhere near the element that changes color using that function and the computed style of the element that is on the background.

Although not perfect, this is where i would start.